# is correct translated code C# to Java?

Tags: c#, java, sorting, compare

Ok i Edited post to short version i want to ask about methods in c#: TryGetValue and sorting list by the compare (IComparator).

I need write this methods in Java so I wrote this code. Asking to developers which know both this language is that correct??

1) First question- TryGetValue is that methods wrote in Java make the same?
c#:

```
     Node value;
    if (!nodes.TryGetValue(nodeId,out value)) return false;
```

to Java:

```
Node value;
    if (!nodes.containsKey(nodeId)){
      return false;
    }else{
      value = nodes.get(nodeId);
    }
```

2)And Sorting by the comparator in java work the same?

```
      static int compareNodes(Node n1, Node n2)
        {
            if (n1.f > n2.f) return 1;
            if (n1.f < n2.f) return -1;
            return 0;
        }

            list.Sort(compareNodes);
```

And this in Java:

```
 @Override
        public int compare(Node nodeFirst, Node nodeSecond) {
            if (nodeFirst.f > nodeSecond.f)
              return 1;
            if (nodeFirst.f < nodeSecond.f)
              return -1;
            return 0;
        }

            Collections.sort(nodeList, new OpenList());
```

Comment: You should post on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead, if you just want a review and do not have a specific question.

Comment: Don't ask questions about translating code. Write the code in the target language, run it, debug it if there are any issues and ask specific questions about those or compiler errors, assuming you've Googled for the cause first. Also, I'm not sure this belongs on [codereview.se], as that site is for fully working code, and it's not clear whether or not this code has been tested at all (and I have similar concerns about asking about code translation there).

Answer (score 2):

After just a quick glance over your code, I can't see any real problems with it. No guarantees though.

If you really want to  be sure, you should probably create unit-tests to verify the behavior in both C# and in Java. That will require a little more work, but will be a lot safer than depending on reviews here.